# How to open and close rich:popupPanel from the same link

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I follow this example from the showcase: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=login&skin=blueSky
it show how I can click on a link to open a popupPanel and append that panel to the same position of that link. But I want so that if I click again, it will close the panel. Anyone know how to achieve that? Here is my code

```
    <h:outputLink value="#" id="sb-dd-ol" >
        <rich:componentControl event="click" operation="show" target="sb-dd-pp">
            <a4j:param noEscape="true" value="event"/>
            <rich:hashParam>
                <a4j:param noEscape="true" name="top"
                           value="jQuery(#{rich:element('sb-dd-ol')}.parentNode).offset().top + 
                                  jQuery(#{rich:element('sb-dd-ol')}.parentNode).height()" />
                <a4j:param noEscape="true" name="left" 
                           value="jQuery(#{rich:element('sb-dd-ol')}.parentNode).offset().left" />
            </rich:hashParam>
        </rich:componentControl>
        Test
    </h:outputLink>
    <rich:popupPanel id="sb-dd-pp" autosized="true" modal="false" 
                     moveable="false" resizeable="false" followByScroll="false">
        This is a test
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can extend PopupPanel prototype, like this:

```
jQuery.extend(RichFaces.ui.PopupPanel.prototype, {
    toggle: function(event, opts) {
        if (this.shown) {
            this.hide(event, opts);
        } else {
            this.show(event, opts);
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can use `operation="toggle"` in componentControl (alternative is to add `onclick="#{rich:component('sb-dd-pp')}.toggle();"` on the link).

Answer (score 0):

not well aware of richfaces 4, but modalpanel renders div, its visibility may be controlled with simple js:

```
var isShown = false;
function onlinkclick() {
  if(isShown) {
      hideElement();
  } else {
      showElement();
  }
  isShown = !isShown;
}
```